# PHP Regular Expression To Match Any URL Except Those From Example.com

Tags: php, regex, url

Provide an example for the pseudo-regex: Match every url except those from example.com and example2.com according to the PHP regexp syntax.

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
$patternToMatch = "@https?://[^(example.com|example2.com)]\"*@i";
```

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, please tag it as such.

Comment: Lol, no. This is not homework. I am just new to regex. But thanks for the insult! How about an answer?

Comment: Not an insult; just quality control. Often questions phrased in this way are - see how the first paragraph looks kinda like an assignment's requirements might. That's all :)

Comment: Yea I guess I can see how it might look like that... I just figured instead of writing "I'm trying to..." or "I want to do this..." I would write a bit more professionally.

Comment: Yes, the question as posted looks like it was copied from a homework assignment. It does not make it look professional, it makes it look like it's not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that within a class definition (`[]`) special characters such as `(` and `|` lose their meaning.

A better solution is to match on example.com or example2.com and then proceed only for negative tests.

Comment: Thanks Segfault, looks like I have to remove all example.com urls, then search for any remaining urls, right? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regular expressions for things you don't need to.

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
if ($parts && $parts['host'] != 'example.com' && $parts['host'] != 'example2.com') {
    // the URL seems OK
}
```

Comment: Lukas, I am trying to extract urls from a text document. I do not have the urls on hand. I do need regex.

Answer (score 1):

No, everything between square brackets will match just one character. For example the regex:

```
[^example]
```

will match any **single** character other than `e`, `x`, `a`, `m`, `p`, `l` and `e`.

Try negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
@https?://(www\.)?(?!example2?.com)@i
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had the answer. 
This will do the matching that you want.

```
$patternToMatch = "@https?://(example.com|example2.com)@i";
```

Comment: Thanks aberpaul, but that looks like it would ONLY find example.com and example2.com - I want everything BUT example.com and example2.com

Comment: I am assuming (maybe wrongly that) you would be able to use PHP? to check if the match returned true/false. I can see segfault thought along these lines.